# any tools available to check process is running in 64 bit or 32bit

Tags: c#, .net

it is .net/C# application, an exe is provided and the os is 64 bit,  i want to know whether the process runs in 64 bit or 32 bit.

Is there any tool to that tells process is  running in 64 bit or 32 bit mode?

Comment: Look at the task manager - a `*32` will be appended to the names of processes that are 32 bit (assuming 64bit Windows OS).

Answer (score 4):

```
Environment.Is64BitProcess ( fw 4).........
```

also please notice about this one :

```
Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem
```

Answer (score 0):

Appending Royi's answer you can try this also:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE");
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers are about how to write an app that would check it for you. If I understand your question correctly you only need to see if a process is 32 bit or 64 bit. If that's true you only need a Windows built-in task manager. All processes that run in 32 bit mode are marked with `*32` in the Process tab.